# Option buttons used in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have another problem, which I can't solve. This time it refers to option buttons.

I have one group of two buttons (YES and NO) and I have three more groups of one button each. The idea is, if it is NO button "on", then all tree groups should have property "Enabled" value "false". Basically, they should be blocked.
If it is YES button "on", then all tree groups should have property "Enabled" value "true". All tree groups should be "on" or "off" depending on whether I click on them and how many times. Those three buttons are independent and can be in combinations with each other "on" or "off".

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

i tried with the code:

```
Private Sub V1028_Click()
    Dim E As Shape
        If ActiveDocument.Shapes(91) = True Then
            Set E = ActiveDocument.Shapes(96)
            E.Visible = True
            Set E = ActiveDocument.Shapes(97)
            E.Visible = True
            Set E = ActiveDocument.Shapes(98)
            E.Visible = True
        End If
End Sub
```

I got information "Object doesn't support this property or method"!

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- Use a `CheckBox` instead of an `OptionButton` achieve the following:

> All three groups should be "on" or "off" depending on whether I click on them and how many times

- Assumes the first OptionButton control is named `OptionButton1`

```vb
Option Explicit
' OptionButton1 change event code
Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()
    Dim ctl As InlineShape
    Dim i As Long, ctlName As Long, opVal As Boolean
    Const CTL_TYPE = "CheckBox"
    For Each ctl In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        With ctl.OLEFormat.Object
            If .Name = "OptionButton1" Then
                opVal = .Value
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next
    For Each ctl In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        With ctl.OLEFormat
            If ctl.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
                If TypeName(.Object) = CTL_TYPE Then
                    .Object.Object.Enabled = opVal
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Effectively Using ActiveX Form Controls in Microsoft Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa140269(v=office.10)?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taller gave you very good advice.

You can also make CheckBoxes invisible and set their values to False when you click OptionButton that should disable them.

You need to write the code below for every OptionButton that is supposed to enable / disable other content controls. BTW, don't forget to group OptionButtons properly.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Change() 'change content control names if necessary
    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        CheckBox1.Visible = True 'or CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    End If

    If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
        CheckBox1.Visible = False 'or CheckBox1.Enabled = False 
        CheckBox1.Value = False 
    End If
End Sub
```